# Using SET in mysqli query

Tags: php, mysql

I've got this query to work in the editor but now that I transfer the Code into the table code I can't seem to get it to work...

Is there something I'm doing wrong in order for this to work in the php?

Having never used the SET in a mysql query before I assume it has something to do with this, I've tried moving the SET part to separate it to no avail but not sure whether it's just something really simple that I'm missing?

```
<table data-role="table" id="table-column" data-theme="f" data-mode="table" class="ui-responsive table-stroke table-stripe">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th style="text-align: center" data-priority="persist">Date Recorded</th>
                    <th style="text-align: center" data-priority="1">Max Temp C°</th>
                    <th style="text-align: center" data-priority="1">rH%</th>
                    <th style="text-align: center" data-priority="2">Hours</th>
                    <th style="text-align: center" data-priority="2">Hours Running Total</th>
                    <th style="text-align: center" data-priority="persist">pH</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <?php
                        if (mysqli_connect_errno())
                          {
                          echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
                          }

                         $result = mysqli_query($link, "SET @runtot:= 0;
SELECT   q1.dated, max_temp, max_rh, q1.c, (@runtot := @runtot + q1.c) AS rt
FROM
(SELECT datestamp AS dated,
   max_temp,
   max_rh,
   sum(hours) AS c,
   ph
FROM hours
WHERE hours > 0 AND username = '$_SESSION[USERNAME]' AND batch_no = '$_SESSION[batch_no]'
GROUP BY dated
ORDER BY dated) AS q1");


                        if (!$result) {
                            die("Query to show fields from table failed");
                        }
                        $fields_num = mysqli_num_fields($result);
                        for($i=0; $i<$fields_num; $i++)
                        {
                            $field = mysqli_fetch_field($result);
                        }
                        while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result))
                        {
                    ?>
                    <td style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle"><?php echo "$row[0]"?></td>
                    <td style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle"><?php echo "$row[1]"?></td>
                    <td style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle"><?php echo "$row[2]"?></td>
                    <td style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle"><?php echo "$row[3]"?></td>
                    <td style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle"><?php echo "$row[4]"?></td>
                    <td style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle"><?php echo "$row[5]"?></td>
                </tr>
                <?php
                    }
                    mysqli_free_result($result)
                ?>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

Comment: These are actually two queries separated by `;`. I doubt if mysqli_query likes multiple queries. You could use a cross join "trick" to initialize variable instead of set statement. Or better, use window functions to calculate running totals (requires MySQL 8).

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add any data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](https://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or data *of any kind* directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: Note: The [object-oriented interface to `mysqli`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.connections.php) is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface where missing a single `i` can cause trouble. Use this style: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era and isn't the best option in new code.

Answer (score 0):

Simply changing the mysql query worked wonders.

Removing the SET.... as the first line of the code and then as the last line of the mysql, the following:

```
ORDER BY d) AS q1, (SELECT @runtot:=0) AS n")
```